# From php to Java - mktime and date

Tags: java, php, date, mktime

I am trying to change a php script to java but I'm stuck in these two lines of code. Does anyone know what the equivalent code is?

```
$Menarche = mktime(2, 0, 0, $Month, $Dday, $Year);
$DueDate = $Menarche + 86400*(280 + ($MCL - 28));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet

Comment: Use java.util.Calendar

Comment: Why not start with [a tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html). [`LocalDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-) for the first line and [`LocalDateTime.plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) for the second part - no need to multiply up to days up to seconds, just use the correct unit to begin with. Just use a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Comment: @ScaryWombat why use a horrible and error prone API when the Date/Time API is now available?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry I am still stuck in one.seven land

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) from the data.  This is a representation of a particular date and time, but without a timezone.

```
final int month = 11;
final int day = 5;
final int year = 1605;

final LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, 2, 0, 0);
```

Now to print it, we can use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
System.out.printf("A date to remember: %s%n", localDateTime.format(formatter));
```

Output:

> A date to remember: 1605-11-05T02:00:00

To do arithmetic with a `LocalDateTime` we can simply use of the of many `plusXXX` methods, for example using months:

```
final LocalDateTime dueDate = localDateTime.plusMonths(9);
System.out.printf("Nine months later: %s%n", dueDate.format(formatter));
```

Output:

> A date to remember: 1606-08-05T02:00:00

Or, if we have a precise duration - we cannot use months because they are "estimated" - you can create a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

```
final Duration gestation = Duration.ofDays(280);
final LocalDateTime dueDate = localDateTime.plus(gestation);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is so helpful!